# How to setup a simple proxy server on my VPS?

Tags: linux, proxy, centos, vps

I would like to setup a simple proxy server on my VPS to use it to browse the browse. I will be the only user so no concern about bandwidth. Can you give me some ideas about it?

Comment: I think you should ask such question on serverfault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into [SSH Tunneling](http://blog.ashurex.com/2012/03/15/creating-ssh-proxy-tunnel-putty/) then. 
No need to set anything up for that, as you're technically just using an SSH connection to your VPS to pipe SOCKS5 proxy traffic through. I use it all the time for proxying quickly.

Otherwise I would look into the HTTP Proxy named [Squid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_%28software%29).

Comment: thx a lot for your help!